# Tensorflow, eager execution and session : Not same results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm working with Tensorflow and trying to convert RGB image to XYZ image. 
When I use eager execution, I get good results but when I use Session, I have a bug. I have spent two days on this problem and can't figure out the solution. 
Would you help me please ? 
Here is the code with eager execution :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

tf.enable_eager_execution()

img = misc.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
file_raw_input = 
    tf.image.convert_image_dtype(
        img, dtype=tf.float32
)
file_raw_input.set_shape([None, None, 3])
srgb_pixels = tf.reshape(file_raw_input, [-1, 3])

linear_mask = tf.cast(
    srgb_pixels <= 0.04045,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
exponential_mask = tf.cast(
    srgb_pixels > 0.04045,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
rgb_pixels = (srgb_pixels / 12.92 * linear_mask) + \
             (((srgb_pixels + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4) * exponential_mask

rgb_to_xyz = tf.constant([
    #    X        Y          Z
    [0.412453, 0.212671, 0.019334], # R
    [0.357580, 0.715160, 0.119193], # G
    [0.180423, 0.072169, 0.950227], # B
], dtype=tf.float32
)

xyz_pixels = tf.matmul(rgb_pixels, rgb_to_xyz)
results = tf.reshape(xyz_pixels, tf.shape(file_raw_input))

plt.imshow(results)
plt.show()
```

With this code, it works, I get this picture (a good one) : [image]

And when I swich to Session with the same code, I got a wrong image. Here is the code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import misc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img = misc.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
file_raw_input = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, dtype=tf.float32)
file_raw_input.set_shape([None, None, 3])
srgb_pixels = tf.reshape(file_raw_input, [-1, 3])

linear_mask = tf.cast(
    srgb_pixels <= 0.04045,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
exponential_mask = tf.cast(
    srgb_pixels > 0.04045,
    dtype=tf.float32
)
rgb_pixels = (srgb_pixels / 12.92 * linear_mask) + \
             (((srgb_pixels + 0.055) / 1.055) ** 2.4) * exponential_mask

rgb_to_xyz = tf.constant([
    #    X        Y          Z
    [0.412453, 0.212671, 0.019334], # R
    [0.357580, 0.715160, 0.119193], # G
    [0.180423, 0.072169, 0.950227], # B
], dtype=tf.float32
)

xyz_pixels = tf.matmul(rgb_pixels, rgb_to_xyz)
results = tf.reshape(xyz_pixels, tf.shape(file_raw_input))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    enhanced_crops = sess.run(results)
    plt.imshow(enhanced_crops)
    plt.show()
```

And with this code, it doesn't work, I get this image :[image]

Anyone has an idea please ? I'm quite in a deadend for the moment

Thank you very much :)

Comment: That's surprising, you should be getting the same image. When I copy and paste your code into python files and run it on my own images, I get the same image with both eager and graph execution. Does this happen to you for all images? Can you check that the versions of python packages you're using are the same in both cases?

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer. It doesn't happen on all my images, only on big images ! To give you an example, the shape of this image is (1428, 2292, 3).
I only have one version of tf in my virtual environnement.
I have implemented it in a jupyter kernel to get deeper in the code but the same error happens. It happens during the matmul opération